# ffmpeg decoding slow calling without avformat_find_stream_info

Tags: performance, ffmpeg, decode, h.264, rtp

I am decoding h264 rtp stream with ffmpeg on android. I found a strange problem: if I don't call `avformat_find_stream_info`,decoding `P frame` takes tens of micro seconds, by contrast, calling `avformat_find_stream_info` before decoding will reduce `P frame` decoding time to less than 1 ms on average. However, `avformat_find_stream_info` itself is time consuming on network streams. Are there anything I can do to make decoding fast **without calling** `avformat_find_stream_info`?

Comment: What info are missing in AVFormatContext and AVCodecContext that cause decoding P frame so slow?

Comment: 10 us is less than 1 ms.  Also, can you describe how you're measuring frame decode times?

Comment: record system time with systemTime(SYSTEM_TIME_MONOTONIC) both before and after  call to avcodec_decode_video2().

Answer (score 3):

When **avformat_find_stream_info** is called, streaming URL(or local file) is scanned by this function to check valid streams in given URL.

That means, in other words, it will decode few packets from given input URL so you can decode packets fast with AVCodecContext, which is initialized in **avformat_find_stream_info**.

I didn't test it but It cannot be decoded without calling **avformat_find_stream_info** In general situation, or maybe it is initialized every time when packet is decoded.

Anyway, that's why **avformat_find_stream_info** consumes network traffic. because, as i said, it pulls first few packets.

If you really want to decode packets fast without calling this function, you should initialize AVCodecContext yourself, manually.

Comment: Surely you can decode frames without calling avformat_find_stream_info beforehand, at least true for mpegts, which i am dealing with. I am not sure what info is needed, so I don't know how to manually populate a AVCodecContext struct. I think I need to RTFSC.

Comment: As i said, it doesn't actually need to call "avformat_find_stream_info". In mpegts format, every frame has it's own codec info so you can play the video even if part of the video's data has lost. Decoder can be opened easily with "avcodec_find_decoder" and "avcodec_open2" function.