# Fast WAV audio decoding with FFMPEG: speeding up avformat_open_input / avformat_find_stream_info

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm implementing an audio reading backend for a machine learning system. This means that decoding should be fast. Potential formats are `.wav`, `.gsm`, `.opus`.

I've implemented audio decoding in FFMPEG: https://github.com/vadimkantorov/readaudio/blob/master/decode_audio_ffmpeg.c

Currently using [`scipy.io.wavfile.read`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/io/wavfile.py#L498) on a 5-second 8khz `.wav` file (typical file for my workload; in practice I'm loading and processing around 1K such files in parallel) takes about 0.02 milliseconds (averaged over reading the same file 100 times). This is reasonable, because `.wav` format is quite simple.

In my FFMPEG code, only calling doing `avformat_open_input` and [`avformat_find_stream_info()`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/42b28565aa852b98d95d8d02f7b0781999f9d533/libavformat/utils.c#L3615) takes about 0.45 milliseconds (with `fmt_ctx->streams[0]-probe_packets=1`) and is 20x slower than `scipy.io.wavfile.read`.

So far `soundfile.read` is 5x slower than `scipy.io.wavfile.read`, `ffmpeg` is 4x slower than `soundfile.read`. So in total `ffmpeg` is 20x slower than `scipy.io.wavfile.read`.

Does anyone know how to avoid taking this latency hit? It still seems that `avformat_open_input` and `avformat_find_stream_info()` do too much work.

I optimized probing by setting `probe_packets=1` and used `AVIO` to control buffered reading. I think IO is now okay optimized...

Log after optimizations:

```
[wav @ 0x55f151175240] Format wav probed with size=2048 and score=99
decode_audio_BEFORE: 0.55 msec
[wav @ 0x55f151175240] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 78 bytes read:65614 seeks:1 nb_streams:1
[wav @ 0x55f151175240] probing stream 0 pp:1
[wav @ 0x55f151175240] Probe with size=4096, packets=2500 detected mp3 with score=1
[wav @ 0x55f151175240] probed stream 0
[wav @ 0x55f151175240] parser not found for codec pcm_s16le, packets or times may be invalid.
[wav @ 0x55f151175240] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 80078 bytes read:145614 seeks:1 frames:20
```

Log before optimizations:

```
decode_audio_BEFORE: 0.61 msec
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 78 bytes read:65614 seeks:1 nb_streams:1
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:32
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] Probe with size=4096, packets=2469 detected mp3 with score=1
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:31
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] Probe with size=8192, packets=2470 detected mp3 with score=1
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:30
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:29
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] Probe with size=16384, packets=2472 detected mp3 with score=1
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:28
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:27
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:26
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:25
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:24
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:23
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:22
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:21
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:20
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:19
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:18
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:17
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:16
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:15
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:14
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:13
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probing stream 0 pp:12
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] probed stream 0
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] parser not found for codec pcm_s16le, packets or times may be invalid.
[wav @ 0x563667d57b60] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 80078 bytes read:145614 seeks:1 frames:20
decode_audio_AFTER: 7.90 msec
```

This problem is well-known, but I couldn't find a workaround so far:

- https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/todo.html#_todo000026
- [ffmpeg decoding slow calling without avformat_find_stream_info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405335/ffmpeg-decoding-slow-calling-without-avformat-find-stream-info/33408001#33408001)

Comment: Why don't you choose the decoder (codec) manually and bypass probing altogether? Like is in this example: http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decode_audio_8c-example.html. Here `avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MP2);` used to choose codec manually.

Comment: Would it also demux the file format for me? At minimum I’d like to support fast reading of wav / opus / gsm. At best I’d also like to support m4a / webm.

I don’t understand well ffmpeg terminology: format / parser / codec.

Comment: Your example uses the «  parser » and doesn’t deal with « format » (while my example used « format » and doesn’t use « parser »). Is « format » needed? Or does « parser » actually suffice?

Comment: It seems that it should be okay, right? If I know the format, I could specify e.g.  `AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S16LE` directly and then just use the parser, right? But it's still interesting why is ffmpeg spending so much time on guessing the format. In the easy case, checking a few header bytes should be sufficient (especially for WAV), shouldn't it?

Comment: As far as I understand, in your case, you don't need probing. The answer is yes.

Comment: Would parser skip the WAV header by itself, right? And for the general case of mp4 (with video and audio), how would it work, would it filter out only audio frames? Basically I don’t understand how the parser and codec enter the demuxing process.

Comment: It seems that WAV demuxer (that parses the WAV header) is separate from the parser: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/wavdec.c

Comment: `avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, input_path, av_find_input_format("wav"), NULL)` (without any `avformat_find_stream_info`) seems to work faster and does no probing (but still takes extra 30-50 useless microseconds which is equivalent to whole of `scipy.io.wavfile parsing`). It also seems that FFMPEG is unable to read all of WAV in a single packet at once because of this line: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/wavdec.c#L703

Comment: I managed to control the packet size with `stream->codecpar->block_align` and it indeed leads to fewer packets, but it somehow increases the time for copying the samples. Quite strange. Some CPU cache effects?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know that much. Anyway, is your problem solved?

Comment: Well, I optimized the FFMPEG reading path 2x, so now it's only 10x slower than direct read, not 20x as it used to be ^^ Getting to 5x (similar to soundfile) would be nice, but it requires deeper understanding of FFMPEG. I guess I should ask at FFMPEG mailing list... In practical terms, I'll have to test this new solution in a more realistic environment of deep learning data loading pipeline and measure if it increases latency (compared to scipy.io.wavfile or not)

Comment: Do you mind to share this part, because I'm interested to know more: _"Well, I optimized the FFMPEG reading path 2x, so now it's only 10x slower than direct read, not 20x as it used to be"_

Comment: My optimization was only this: `avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, input_path, av_find_input_format("wav"), NULL)` (without any `avformat_find_stream_info`)